# Directory phpunit wrong?

Tags: php, terminal, phpunit

i would like to create a separate folder for phpunit. I want to have one folder for all related to unit testing. unit_test is the name. But i get a message:

```
PS C:\Users\dh_netsense.no\utv\NSS-Hyttetjenester> unit_test/vendor/bin/phpunit
PHPUnit 8.4.3 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Usage:
  phpunit [options] UnitTest [UnitTest.php]
  phpunit [options] <directory>
```

How do i configure phpunit so I can run it in this path? I do not see the tests being run now.

Answer (score 2):

Create a phpunit.xml you put in the root directory of your unit_test folder.

`unit_test/phpunit.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    bootstrap="bootstrap.php"
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    colors="true"
    convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
    convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
    convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
    processIsolation="false"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    syntaxCheck="false"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Daniels test suite">
            <directory>./</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <php>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="testing" force="true"/>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing" force="true"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array" force="true"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array" force="true"/>

    </php>
</phpunit>
```

This file will tell phpunit where to look for what files, what environment variables to set, etc... You can do most of this also via command line flags, but having a file to save the settings makes life a lot easier.

Then in your `unit_test` folder you can place your test files, even in subdirectories if you wish. Just keep up with the convention of naming files and test functions.

Files containing tests should be named something like: DanielsFirstApplication**Test**.php

and the test functions with in the files should start with the word test in lowercase. Make sure to give your test functions descriptive names.

> public function **test**DanielsApplicationInitialization() {
>      }

In your WhateverTest.php files you can also have a function named `setUp()` and `tearDown()`. These will be called before each `testYourNameHere()` function so you can initialize your required files there, create models, required files, database records etc... and clean them in the tearDown.

If you want to do different preparation actions for different tests you can use if statements like this in setUp and tearDown

```
if($this->getName() == 'testDanielsApplicationInitialization') {
   // test thing.
}
```

In your bootstrap.php you load all the required files for what framework/application you want to test to be initialized. For example for octobercms I use something like this:

`unit_test/bootstrap.php`

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
$autoloader_exitx = require __DIR__.'/../include/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once(__DIR__.'../../vendor/autoload.php');
require __DIR__.'../../bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once $OCTOBER_PATH.'/bootstrap/app.php';  
$kernel = $app->make(\Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
$request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture();
$app->instance('request', $request);
$kernel->bootstrap();
```

Or whatever your framework uses to load.

If you want any advice, don't make a seperate directory for unit tests away from your main project.

Just include php unit via `composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit` That way it will only be installed on dev machines. You can then create your php unit in your root application directory and make a folder named tests and set your testsuites to the tests folder:

```
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Daniels test suite">
        <directory>./tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
```

This way your projects are always coupled to your tests, and they are still in their own folder.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will use this if our custom testing environment doen't work,